# How to implement onScroll event in ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I want to implement scrolling(horizontal) on my custom view which i have set in `ScrollView`. I have implemented `OnGestureListener` on that activity and trying to achieve scrolling using `onScroll()` event. I am getting onScroll event fired and also i am invalidating my view, still not getting scrolling. I am not getting what i am missing here. Is there any other way or any links regarding this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try these tuto at least for me it worked http://www.androidpeople.com/android-horizontalscrollview-example